# Infinite loop bug in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm new to this platform and I'm still learning to
program in Lua, so, if any newbie errors appear, forgive me.

The following code is from one of the functions in my project that reads the insert
of the user and validates whether or not it is a data of type "Number". If,
the loop will be broken and the function will return the user input, otherwise, the
program will ask the user to enter the data again:

```
function bin.readnum(text)
    local insertion
    if text == nil then text = "Text: " end
    while (insertion == nil) do
        insertion = nil
        print(text)
        insertion = io.read("number")
        if insertion ~= nil then break end
    end
    return insertion
end
```

But, if the user enters a wrong data (string) the function prints the `text`
madly instead of asking the user to re-enter the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `io.read` fails to parse the data it got into a number, it doesn't discard it, but instead leaves it in the buffer for the next call to it. That means that in your code, instead of letting the user enter something else, it'll just keep trying to parse the same non-number forever. To fix it, in your `if insertion ~= nil then` block, do `io.read()` right before `break`, to read and discard the whole invalid line.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Joseph Sible said:

- `io.read("number")` is wrong: 5.1 docs demand `"*n"` and 5.4 docs demand just `"n"` for reading numbers. It probably works nevertheless due to Lua just searching for the chars in the string.
- I recommend just replacing `insertion = io.read("number")` with`insertion = tonumber(assert(io.read(), "EOF"))` - this will read a line and try to parse it as a number; the `assert` gracefully deals with `nil` being returned by `io.read` for EOF.
- You don't need to set `insertion` to `nil`, the later assignment will do that already if what was read is not a valid number.
- Style: Consider replacing your explicit `nil` checks with truthiness checks and removing the parentheses around the `while`-condition. You don't need a `break`, you can immediately return the read number; finally, you can even replace the entire loop with tail recursion.

All in all I'd rewrite it as follows:

```lua
function bin.readnum(text)
    print(text or "Text: ")
    local num = tonumber(assert(io.read(), "EOF"))
    if num then return num end
    return bin.readnum(text)
end
```

or alternatively using a `repeat-until` loop:

```lua
function bin.readnum(text)
    local num
    repeat
        print(text or "Text: ")
        num = tonumber(assert(io.read(), "EOF"))
    until num
    return num
end
```